# Joining between Two tables and showing them in my web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have two Classes Category and Product 1 to many Relationship
here's my Category Class

```
    public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And Here's my Product Class (Copied from northwind)

```
    public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="*")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public int QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="*")]
    public int UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="*")]
    public int UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="*")]
    public int ReorderLevel { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="*")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a Controller Called ProductsController , it has a View Called Index()

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ProductList = from p in db.Products
                          join c in db.Categories.ToList()
                          on p.CategoryID equals c.ID
                          select new {ID =  p.ID, Name = p.Name, QuantityPerUnit = p.QuantityPerUnit,
                              ReorderLevel = p.ReorderLevel, UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice,
                              UnitsInStock = p.UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder = p.UnitsOnOrder, Category = c.Name };

        return View(ProductList.ToList());
    }
```

And Here's the code generated by the Entity Framrwork for the Index view

```
<span>@model IEnumerable<BootstrapSite1.Models.Product></span>
```

My view Reads a collection of Product

```
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QuantityPerUnit)

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitPrice)

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitsInStock)

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitsOnOrder)

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReorderLevel)

        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryID)
```

My problem is as you can see I want to make a join between the CategoryID in Product class and Category Class and replace the Category ID we Category name but the problem is The Product object only accepts An Int not a string so how do I solve this issue thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the name of the Category in the view, you schould add a navigation property to Product model like this:

```
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```